# How can I allow a user to Import a CSV File so that it gets added into the data they inputted already

Tags: python

I'm making a data viewer program and for part of it I need to make an import function that allow users to import a CSV file.

The CSV file contains sales amount, year, month and day.

I am also using a text file to keep track of the imported file so the files cannot be imported more than once.

I'm just lost on where to even start that.

```
import sales
import csv
with open('all_sales.csv', newline='') as f:
    data = list(csv.reader(f))
#display a title
def display_welcome_message():
    print("Welcome to data viewer program")
    
#display a title
def display_welcome_message():
    print("Welcome to data viewer program")
    
def display_menu():
    print("enter sales data")
    print()
    print("COMMAND MENU")
    print("View  - View All Sales")
    print("add   - Add sales")
    print("Menu  - Show menu")
    print("Import - Import file")
    print("Exit  - Exit Program")
    print()
 
total_amount=0
FILENAME = "all_sales.csv"
 
def read_sales():
    all_sales = []
    with open(FILENAME, newline="") as file:
        reader = csv.reader(file)
        for row in reader:
            all_sales.append(row)
    return all_sales
 
 
 
def write_sales(all_sales):
    with open(FILENAME, "w", newline="") as file:
        writer = csv.writer(file)
        writer.writerows(all_sales)
            
#def create_file(all_sales):
    #with open(FILENAME, "w") as file:
        #file.write()
 
def add(all_sales):
    
    amount1 = sales.get_amount()
    
    year1 = sales.get_year()
    
    month1 = sales.get_month()
    
    day1 = sales.get_day()
 
    #month1, day1, year1, print("     "), "amount:", amount1
    add_sales = []
    add_sales.append(month1)
    add_sales.append(day1)a
    add_sales.append(year1)
    add_sales.append(amount1)
    all_sales.append(add_sales)
    write_sales(all_sales)
    print(str(month1), " - ", day1, " - ", year1, "was added")
 
 
def importfile(all_sales):
    print("Enter a file name to import: ")
 
 
def view(all_sales):
    i = 0
    total = 0
    if len(all_sales) == 0:
        print("there are no sales data in the list. \n")
        return
    else:
        print(f"              Date               Quarter     Amount")
        print("---------------------------------------------------------")
        while i < len(all_sales):
            print(str(i+1),".          ",all_sales[i][2],"-",all_sales[i][0],"-",all_sales[i][1],"     ","          $",all_sales[i][3])
            total += all_sales[i][3]
            i += 1            
        print("---------------------------------------------------------")
        print("TOTAL:                                       $", total)
 
 
def calculate_quarter():
    if month1 <= 3:
        quarter1 = 1
    elif month1 > 3 and month1 <= 6:
        quarter1 = 2
    elif month1 > 6 and month1 <=9:
        quarter1 = 3
    elif month1 > 9 and month1 <=12:
        quarter1 = 4
 
 
def main():
    display_welcome_message()
    display_menu()
    all_sales = []
    sales_list = []
 
    
    while True:
        command = input('enter command: ')
        if command == 'view':
            view(sales_list)
        elif command == 'add':
            add(sales_list)
        elif command == 'menu':
            display_menu()
        elif command == 'exit':
            break
        else:
            print("not a valid command. Please try again. \n")
    print("Bye!")
 
 
    
if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

```
def importfile(all_sales):
    filename = input("Import file name:  ")
```

I have what I'm trying to work with in the def importfile(all_sales): but I'm not sure how to get it to look like what I need it to, see this reference:

https://imgur.com/gallery/rmIfU4E

Comment: as you did to construct `data` you will do to `extend()` data by reading a csv. The initial one has a hardcoded path but your import will use a path that you get by asking the user to `imput()` it.

Answer (score 0):

If you want `read_sales()` to import multiple files, you may want to:

1. keep a list of files `MY_SALES_FILES`, instead of a single file `FILENAME`
2. have `importfile()` add new files to the list
3. have `read_sales()` read from the list

```
    MY_SALES_FILES = [ "all_sales.csv" ]

    def importfile():
        MY_SALES_FILES.append(input("Import file name:  "))
    
    def read_sales():
        all_sales = []
        for filename in MY_SALES_FILES:
            with open(filename, newline="") as file:
                reader = csv.reader(file)
                for row in reader:
                    all_sales.append(row)
        return all_sales
```